# linq groupby without time field vb.net

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq

I've been struggling with this for weeks. I can seem to find the answers in C# but not vb.net since VB.net is using anonymous types. I can group my column, but I want just the short date (11/11/11) and not the date and time (11/11/11 11:11:11). Here is what I've got currently:

```
Dim preSort = SortedTimeline.GroupBy(Function(GroupTime) New With {Key GroupTime.Scheduled_Start})
```

This creates groups only if the time also matches. And I can't put any .tostring or any date magic on the Key due to it being anonymous.

Any idea???

Comment: Can't you just use `GroupTime.Scheduled_Start.Date`?

Comment: `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` is what you need. It doesn't matter if you are using C# or VB.NET.

Comment: dbfunctions tells me "Anonymous type member name can be inferred only fromm a single or qualified name with no arguments"  I had forgotten but gone down that road before.

Comment: @DavidG No VS 2015 doesn't like that. Says "Date is not a member of Date?"

Comment: No need of anonymous type, simply `GroupBy(Function(GroupTime) DbFunctions.TruncateTime(GroupTime.Scheduled_Start))` should do.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev You, sir, are a GOD!!! I'm not kidding!!!! I've Googled and Googled and Googled this so much every link that comes up on the first 3 pages of every groupby search I do is already read!!! LOL Turn this into an answer and I'll upvote the heck out of it.

Comment: Lol, I don't think this is extraordinary - a pretty standard answer in C#, juts needed to find and look the VB.NET documentation (since I'm C#-er). But glad it helped :)

Comment: I had tried it before, but I guess I still had the key in there. It wouldn't let me do it with the key. AWESOME!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally your would use the `DateTime.Date` property, but EF6 does not support it and requires using [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx) method for tat purpose.

Also, VB.NET does not demand using anonymous type (although I'm pretty sure there is way to specify the anonymous type member *name*). When you group by a single field like in your case, you could use simply the following (as shown in [Group By VB.NET example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534492(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
.GroupBy(Function(GroupTime) DbFunctions.TruncateTime(GroupTime.Scheduled_Start))
```

Comment: This was exactly right! Worked perfectly!!!! I guess I've only got 10 rep and need 15 to upvote. If anyone sees this please upvote this for me!!! Thanks!!!